# Python unittest - testing multiple files with the same name

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am attempting to test multiple functions with the same name and signature. (Student assignment submissions.) My setup currently looks like this:

```
TestCases/
    __init__
    testcase1.py
    submission1/
        func.py
    submission2/
        func.py
    submission3/
        func.py
```

Each `func.py` contains a function named `foo`. I would like to test each occurrence of foo with the same test suite. The standard unittest setup of

```
    import unittest
    from func import foo

    class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_empty(self):
            self.assertTrue(foo(''))
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

has (unsurprisingly) problems with the `from func import foo` line since func is not in the same folder, and I cannot seem to get it to pick up the proper import dynamically.

It struck me that I could take advantage of having already extended the base class and eliminate the need for the import by doing something like:

```
    import unittest

    class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

        def __init__(self, foo):
            self.foo = foo

        def test_empty(self):
            self.assertTrue(self.foo(''))
```

and in my test program instantiate a `TestFoo` object and pass it the function to test:

```
tf = TestFoo(foo)
```

but then I haven't been able to properly define and call the test suite.

Or is there an entirely different approach that would do what I need?

Comment: Looping over the submissions and getting references to the individual `func.py` files is not a problem - I can open the individual ones and see their contents. Getting the imports to work properly within the loop is a problem. I either get various import errors depending on the technique I try, or it ends up testing the first import multiple times.

Comment: I'm not actually *doing* anything. Although I've tried a number of approaches, none work; what I'm interested in is suggestions on a working approach, rather than corrections for code that may be not worth correcting. I see the following possibilities, and if you've done one of these that work then even knowing I'm on the right road would be extraordinarily helpful. Thus:

Comment: Whoops - more for above:

Comment: Can't even comment correctly. Should I: copy the test file `testcase1.py` to each subfolder and run it there; copy each `func.py` to the root `TestCases` folder and test it, overwriting with each new one; not copy the file at all but change the imports and references dynamically as I run through the subfolders; some other approach entirely?